# Removing Item from BindableCollection of ShellViewModel with ChildViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I have a ShellViewModel with a `BindableCollection` which is bound to a Canvas with the help of ItemControl.

I add ChildViewModel derived from Screen, to this bindableCollection with the help of a button  from ShellViewModel.

I have a closebutton in the ChildViewModel, and on clicking this button, i want to remove item from BindableCollection of ShellViewModel,

Please help.

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I think inheriting from *Conductor<T>.Collection.OneActive* on ShellViewModel would work better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to maintain your existing implementation, you can always create an event and use the EventAggregator. Your ChildViewModel would need to publish the event, and the ShellViewModel would need to implement the `IHandle<ChildViewModelMessage>` interface. As part of that implementation, it would be able to remove the ChildViewModel from the BindableCollection. Generally, it would look something like this:

```
public class ChildViewModelMessage {
    // Implementation here
}

public class ShellViewModel : IHandle<ChildViewModelMessage> {
    ...
    public void Handle(ChildViewModelMessage message) {
        // Handle here
    }
}

public class ChildViewModel {
    ...
    public IEventAggregator Events { get; set; }
    protected void HandleClose() {
        this.Events.Publish(new ChildViewModelMessage());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

If you need to talk between different viewmodels, you should use a messenger. Here's an example from the mvvm light toolkit : http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/09/27/mvvm-light-toolkit-messenger-v2-beta.aspx